# Can the href tag of jnlp file is pointed to .jsp file to match the location rule in DeploymentRuleSet

Tags: java, jsp, href, java-web-start, jnlp

We are trying to use Java Deployment Rule set feature to launch our web application with different JRE version. As all the application JRE files are unsigned, we have to give the DRS rule id as location of the jnlp file which should match with the jnlp file location. But the jnlp file is created dynamically by JSP(when user clicks the link, .jnlp file is created  by adding cookie information to the application-desc tag)

Currently href tag is not defined in the .jnlp file creation(only spec and codebase tags are defined in the jnlp tag), as the jnlp file is created dynamically can we give the hreg tag value to the .jsp file path and if yes, will the deployment rule set matches the rule and redirects to the specified JRE version.